# Evaluate $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n$ or $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{w^2-1}+i}w-1\right)^m$

Tags: derivatives, generating-functions, fixed-points, transcendental-equations, lagrange-inversion

With [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$x\sin(x)=1\iff x=\{2\pi k+\csc^{-1}(x),(2k+1)\pi-\csc^{-1}(x)\}$$

Therefore:

$$x_{2k}=2k\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!} \left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n\right|_{2k\pi}
\\x_{2k+1}=(2k+1)\pi+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n\right|_{(2k+1)\pi}$$

with examples [shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5B+3.0+pi+%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28acsc%28w%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cw-%3E3+*pi%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+sin%28x%29%2Cx%3D4+pi+%2Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B%28acsc%28w%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cw%3D4.0+pi+). Next use [Stirling S1](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/StirlingS1/23/02/0001/):

$$\begin{align}\frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n=(-i)^n \frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\frac{\ln^n\left(\frac{\sqrt{w^2-1}+i}w\right)}{n!}=(-1)^n\sum_{m=n}^\infty\frac{S_m^{(n)}}{m!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{w^2-1}+i}w-1\right)^m\end{align}$$

Also, the binomial theorem presents $\displaystyle\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{w^2-1}+i}w\right)^j$, but that is still too complicated. Additionally, no generating functions from [these polynomials](https://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/) matched it.

What is $\displaystyle\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\csc^{-1}(w)^n$ as a triple sum or simpler? We could find all solutions to $\csc(x)=x$ explicitly then.